# How to use an array to index the last dim of a second array

Tags: python, numpy

Assume that `X.shape = (h, w, d)` and that `Y.shape = (h, w)` contains values (indices) in `range(d)`.

How can I take the elements in X (from the last dim) using the indices in Y?

That is, I would like to do something like `X[Y]` that will return an h x w array where Y was used as the indices in the last dim d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [numpy.take_along_axis](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy-take-along-axis):

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng()

h, w, d = 2, 3, 4
x = rng.random((h, w, d))
y = rng.integers(0, d, (h, w))

x, y, np.take_along_axis(x, y[..., None], axis=-1)[..., 0]
```

Output:

```
(array([[[0.51705108, 0.68891581, 0.84475703, 0.77938839],
         [0.02115493, 0.47689898, 0.19786926, 0.73959225],
         [0.40821923, 0.0119006 , 0.89595898, 0.81798467]],
 
        [[0.60350791, 0.11501983, 0.15932539, 0.35923036],
         [0.27939872, 0.13691148, 0.47528086, 0.71320657],
         [0.98294212, 0.75039413, 0.06087527, 0.68233282]]]),
 array([[0, 2, 0],
        [3, 0, 0]]),
 array([[0.51705108, 0.19786926, 0.40821923],
        [0.35923036, 0.27939872, 0.98294212]]))
```

Comparison with [Ulises' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76682171/15456681):

```
assert np.array_equal(np.take_along_axis(x, y[..., None], axis=-1)[..., 0], x[ np.eye(d)[y].astype(np.bool)].reshape(y.shape))
%timeit np.take_along_axis(x, y[..., None], axis=-1)[..., 0]
%timeit x[ np.eye(d)[y].astype(np.bool)].reshape(y.shape)
```

Output:

```
9.42 µs ± 91.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
55.8 µs ± 463 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Comment: could you compare with `np.choose` solution

Comment: @UlisesBussi I'm not convinced it's correct - with ```h, w, d = 200, 300, 50``` I get ```ValueError: Need at least 0 and at most 32 array objects.``` with numpy 1.24.2

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit

---

The shortest way to select elements is swaping dimensions in `x` then use `choose` to select `y` values:

```
np.choose(y, x.transpose(2,0,1))
```

---

##### Old solution

---

suposing you have `x`, and `y`, you could create a categorical array using `y` and use it to select  on `x`:

example:

```
#create arrays
h,w,d = 3,3,4
x = np.arange(h*w*d).reshape(h,w,d)
y = np.random.randint(d,size=(h,w))

#categorical y
cat_y =  np.eye(d)[y]

# select elements from x
x_sel = x[cat_y.astype(bool)]

#reshape to original form
x_out = x_sel.reshape(y.shape)
```

or in one line:

```
xx = x[ np.eye(d)[y].astype(np.bool)].reshape(y.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
X[np.arange(h)[:,None], np.arange(w), Y]
```

The idea is to  index the first two dim with arrays that `broadcast` with `Y`. `(h,1), (w,), (h,w)`  That's the general principle for all advanced indexing. That's we had to do before they added `take_along`.

`ix_`, `meshgrid`  and `ogrid` could also be used to make these arrays.

Comment: Thanks, why do you need the extra dimension in the first index? (np.arange(h)[:, None])
Not sure I understand what's happening inside the square brackets

Comment: It makes a (h,1) shaped array.

Comment: Thanks, again, sorry I wasn't clear, I meant I'm not sure what happening inside the X[] (X[np.arange(h)[:,None], np.arange(w), Y]) brackets... you created an (h, 1) vector on the first entry, then an (w, ) array before the final (h,w) Y entry... so I'm still not sure what's happening there before the actual indexing takes place.

Comment: I create 3 arrays, and pass them to the indexing 'function'.  Since they are compatible in a broadcasting sense, numpy selects a block of elements. That's called `advanced indexing`